# SQL Data Transfers

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have all out real time databases set on Sql 2008 R2 Enterprise and we want to send that data for reporting servers continuously.

The only reporting server we have is Sql 2016 Standard.

We thought of going ahead and set up replication between both the servers, but unfortunately this is not possible to set up replication from 2008 to 2016.

I dont have a clue why the reporting server was set up to 2016 if they wanted to replicate the data. This was done by someone i dont know.

We have some restrictions:

1. We dont want to set up Replication from 2008 to 2012/2014 and then again to 2016.
2. We are thinking of not to push the data from 2008 because there are many more real time process on the same server(over 500 jobs)

Any real suggestions related to this will be appreciated.

Comment: Update from 2008 to 2016 is not an option?

Comment: It is an option but as i said we have some other process running on the same server and we replicating to couple of other servers which are 2008 and 2005.